# How to monitoring fortinet-fortigate VPN site to site with elastic on azure

Tags: azure, network-monitoring

I'm trying to figure out how to monitor a VPN site-to-site on Azure, and the VPN is set up using Fortinet - Fortigate.

I took a look at the Elastic documentation, but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Can you please drop a hint on where to look or share any suggestions? If it's not doable with the Elastic Stack, what other tools or platforms do you recommend?

NOTE : Why elastic? we are trying to use this tool as our observability tool, to monitoring the different stack that with have on azure (infra, apps, Networking , in the future AIops , etc... ). And one of the requirements that we found is our products is monitoring the vpn site to site.

**UPDATE** The Vpn site to site use fortinet-fortigate virtual appliance on azure, so I don't have acces to install nothing inside this VM. What we can do only is activate the syslog feature and send the logs to a different VM as a syslog server.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I'd get a recurrent `ping command` from and to both sides of the VPN to detect that the tunnel is up, if you're a powershell, you can follow [this](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/send-email-message-on-failed-ping.html).

Comment: I'm obviously missing something, but how does Elastic factor in your decision making? That is not  a product that is particularly relevant for availability monitoring in my experience but maybe you deploy/use it differently? - The best solution is usually not to deploy something completely new but to tie in with your existing monitoring and alerting infrastructure, and when you don't have anything yet, to select something versatile that can solve more (future) needs than only monitor 1 VPN link.

Comment: Or you simply get the appliance to notify you  https://community.fortinet.com/t5/FortiGate/Technical-Tip-Email-alert-notification-when-IPsec-VPN-tunnel-is/ta-p/196582

Comment: What kind of VPN? ExpressRoute?

Answer (score 0):

You could have on both sites a VM and use Azure connection monitor to do synthetic tests of the connection. That could feed into Azure Monitor and queried by elastic

Or using a runbook
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-monitor-with-azure-automation#next-steps